# Como calcular a diferença entre duas datas?

Tags: php, data

Qual a forma mais prática de encontrar a diferença de tempo entre duas datas no formato padrão usado pelo MySQL (YYYY-MM-DD)? Ex:

**Data 1:** 2013-12-11
**Data 2:** 1994-04-17

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Uma das formas de fazer isto orientado a objetos, é usando a classe [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), a mesma possui o método [diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) que retorna um objeto [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), que representa o intervalo entre duas datas distintas:

Seguindo o exemplo de datas:

```php
$data1 = new DateTime( '2013-12-11' );
$data2 = new DateTime( '1994-04-17' );

$intervalo = $data1->diff( $data2 );

echo "Intervalo é de {$intervalo->y} anos, {$intervalo->m} meses e {$intervalo->d} dias";
```

Comment: `DateTime->diff()` funciona a partir do php 5.3. Se quiser a diferença em dias, use `$intervalo->days`.

Answer (score 31):

Você pode usar também a função do MySQL **[DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)** <sup>(en)</sup> que é bem simples, veja os exemplos:

```sql
SELECT DATEDIFF('2013-01-01','2012-03-01')
```

No caso acima, passei duas datas "manualmente", podem ser dois campos:

Imagine que tem uma tabela com os campos `data_registro` e `ultimo_acesso`, se quiser mostrar ao usuário o número de dias entre o cadastro e o ultimo acesso, voce pode usar:

```sql
SELECT DATEDIFF(ultimo_acesso, data_registro)
```

Se precisar calcular a diferença entre uma data qualquer e a data atual, você pode usar a função **[NOW()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)** <sup>(en)</sup> do MySQL:

```sql
SELECT DATEDIFF( NOW(), ultimo_acesso)
```

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar, se a data do segundo parametro for maior que a do primeiro, o resultado será negativo.

Comment: Deve-se ficar atento às tags da pergunta, no caso não têm nenhuma tag relatada ao MySQL, apenas cito na pergunta, mas sem relação. Mas agrega. :)

Comment: @JCM geralmente deixo no banco o que posso, pra desonerar a lógica da aplicação, mas obrigado

Answer (score 18):

Solução disponível a partir da versão 5.3+ do PHP:

```php
$date  = new DateTime('2012-12-25 12:00:00');
$date2 = new DateTime('2013-12-25 12:00:00');

var_dump($date->diff($date2));
```

**Saída:**

```php
object(DateInterval)[3]
  public 'y' => int 1
  public 'm' => int 0
  public 'd' => int 0
  public 'h' => int 0
  public 'i' => int 0
  public 's' => int 0
  public 'weekday' => int 0
  public 'weekday_behavior' => int 0
  public 'first_last_day_of' => int 0
  public 'invert' => int 0
  public 'days' => int 365
  public 'special_type' => int 0
  public 'special_amount' => int 0
  public 'have_weekday_relative' => int 0
  public 'have_special_relative' => int 0
```

<sup>Estou utilizando php 5.5.7 aqui, então essa saída pode conter menos campos caso a versão seja inferior.</sup>

Answer (score 17):

```
return date_diff(date_create($data_fim), date_create($data_ini))->format('%d');//days
```

Comment: a tua resposta foi sinalizada por baixa qualidade, devido a tamanho e conteúdo. Apesar de poder ser válida, tenta desenvolver um pouco mais.

Comment: Mas o que ele digitou não precisa de mais. Está perfeito e foi o que me ajudou, foi a melhor resposta comparada aos outros que encheram linguiça de código. Parabéns.

Answer (score -4):

```
$resultado = strtotime($data_inicial.' + '.$data_final);
```

Answer (score -5):

**Segue código comentado:**

```php
//adicionar as tags *PHP* **<?php** ao início e **?>** ao final do código
// substitua $pacientes['data']) pela data do nascimento ou pela primeira data, isto é, a mais antiga.

$data1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($pacientes['data'])); // data nascimento
$data2 = date("Y-m-d"); // data atual
$data2b = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year')); // data daqui um ano
$data3 = $data2b - date('z', strtotime($data2)); // primeiro dia próximo ano
$data3b = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month')); // data daqui um mês
$data4 = $data3b - date('z', strtotime($data2)); // primeiro dia próximo mês

$d1_ano = date('Y', strtotime($data1));
$d2_ano = date('Y', strtotime($data2));
$r_ano = $d2_ano - $d1_ano;
$d1_dia = ($d1_ano*365.25)+date('z', strtotime($data1));
$d2_dia = ($d2_ano*365.25)+date('z', strtotime($data2)); // z = nª dia/ano

$r_dia = $d2_dia - $d1_dia; //dias vividos desde nascimento

$r_ano = $r_dia / 365.25; //anos vividos desde nascimento

$r_mes = $r_ano*30; // meses vividos desde nascimento

$f1_ano = date('Y', strtotime($data1));
$f2_ano = date('Y', strtotime($data3));
$rf_ano = $f2_ano - $f1_ano;
$f1_dia = ($f1_ano*365.25)+date('z', strtotime($data1));
$f2_dia = ($f2_ano*365.25)+date('z', strtotime($data1));

$rf_dia = $f2_dia - $f1_dia; // dias p/ próximo aniversário

$rf_ano = $rf_dia / 365.25; // idade (ano) atual 

$f_dia = ($r_dia - $rf_dia); // idade (dia) atual ou dias vividos este ano

$f_mes = $f_dia/30; // idade (mês) atual ou meses vividos este ano


if($rf_ano <= 1) {
    $concordancia_ano = "ano";
} else {
    $concordancia_ano = "anos";
};

if($f_mes <= 1) {
    $concordancia_mes = "mês";
} else {
    $concordancia_mes = "meses";
};


echo floor($rf_ano); echo " "; echo $concordancia_ano; echo " e "; echo floor($f_mes); echo " "; echo $concordancia_mes; echo ".";
```

B'H todo o conhecimento.