# Trabalhando com verificações de datas e prazos

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, data, conversão, strtotime

Estou um um problema de logica em minha aplicação.
Galera é o seguinte, no modulo de projetos do meu sistema existe um prazo para entrega do projeto.
Eu preciso saber o seguinte.

> Se o   dia de hoje for 1 semana (7 Dias)  antes do prazo final, mandoamarelo pra coluna status(Essas cores ja tenho implementado só falta a logica rsrsr)
>
> Se o dia de hoje for 2 Semanas (14 Dias) antes do prazo final, mando Verde para coluna de status.
>
> Se estourado mando vermelho

até agora só tenho verificado se esta estourado ou não com uma logica básica
variável `$recebeData` = Data Final do projeto
variável $diaHoje --'

```
<?php
            $recebeData = date_converter($date);
            $diaHoje = date('Y-m-d');
            if(strtotime($recebeData) >= strtotime($diaHoje)){
                }
                  jogo verde no status
        else {
               jogo vermelho no status
}
        ?>
```

Me ajudem a fazer a jogar amarelo se faltar 7 dias antes do prazo e verde se faltar 14 dias antes!

Answer (score 0):

Bom, supondo que você recebe a data de um banco de dados e faça essa verificação no php, pode usar a classe **Datetime->diff()**. Inclusive isso já foi tratado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/como-calcular-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-duas-datas).

Procurei utilizar os mesmos nomes de variáveis do seu sistema, para melhor entendimento.

```
$recebeData = new DateTime( '2016-05-08' );
$diaHoje = new DateTime();

$dias = $recebeData->diff( $diaHoje );

if (($dias->days) > 14) {
    echo '<div style="background: red; width: 200px; height: 200px"><div>';
}elseif (($dias->days) > 7) {
    echo '<div style="background: green; width: 200px; height: 200px"><div>';
}else{
    echo '<div style="background: yellow; width: 200px; height: 200px"><div>';
}
```

Explicando melhor o código, a variavel **$recebeData** receberá a data final do projeto.

A variável **$diaHoje** recebe obviamente a data atual, e a **$dias** faz o calculo dos dias corridos. Caso queira mostrar o total de dias, poderá exibir o objeto $dias->days.

Depois foi feito um if utilizando o parametro de cores informado e um echo com um box simples exemplificando as cores.

Answer (score 0):

é galera muito obrigado pela ajuda.
Porém resolvi o problema com a seguinte logica

';
echo "HOJE: ".$hoje;
echo '';
echo "VENCIDO: ".$bd_vencido;
echo '';
echo "5 DIAS: ".$bd_5dias;
echo '';
echo "8 DIAS: ".$bd_8dias;
echo '';

//colocar aqui uma das opções:
// $bd_vencido
// $bd_5dias
// $bd_8dias
$bd = $hoje;

if ($bd <= $hoje)
{
   echo "vencido - vermelho";
} else
   {
      if ($bd > ($hoje + 604800))
      {
         echo "faltam mais de 7 dias - verde";
      } else
          {
              echo "faltam menos de 7 dias - amarelo;";
          }
   }

?>
valeus a todos

Answer (score -1):

Por uma questão de desempenho, faça com que o banco de dados faça o calculo de diferença entre as datas. Veja a função DATEDIFF() do mysql [Clique aqui para ver exemplo](http://www.codigosnaweb.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7302).

Supondo que o retorno de datas seja retornado na variável $**tempoConclusao** nesse caso faça a verificação abaixo e use a variável $status para passar um nome de classe do CSS.

Assim quando fizer o html, inclua uma classe na tag span. Ex: `<span class="<?echo $status;?>"</span>`

```
//Verifica se está entre 1 e 7 dias
if ($tempoConclusao > 0 && $tempoConclusao <= 7 ) {
                    $status = "corAmarelo";
} 
//se o prozo é maior que 7 dias
elseif ($tempoConclusao > 7) {
      $status = "corVerde";
} 
//tempo negativo, ou seja, já estourado
else {
      $status = "corVermelho";
}
```