# Subtrair variáveis Datetime

Tags: php

Tenho dois campos datetime e gostaria de saber a diferença entre eles.
Estou desenvolvendo em Php Gtk, então as funções tem que ser de mais baixo nível possível.

Comment: Isso responde? [Como calcular a diferença entre duas datas?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57/91)

Comment: Meu caro, veja se isso pode lhe ajudar Link:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/como-calcular-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-duas-datas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma das formas de fazer isto orientado a objetos, é usando a classe DateTime, a mesma possui o método diff que retorna um objeto DateInterval, que representa o intervalo entre duas datas distintas:

Seguindo o exemplo de datas:

```
  $data1 = new DateTime( '2013-12-11' );
  $data2 = new DateTime( '1994-04-17' );

  $intervalo = $data1->diff( $data2 );

  echo "Intervalo é de {$intervalo->y} anos, {$intervalo->m} meses e {$intervalo->d} dias";
```

Fonte: [Como calcular a diferença entre duas datas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/como-calcular-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-duas-datas)