# Como calcular a diferença de tempo entre determinadas horas?

Tags: php, postgresql, data

```
public function checks($request)
{
    $token = $this->count->All();

    foreach($token as $tokens){
      $tokens->system_contador_user_update_at
```

Com isso eu pego a hora em que está gravado no banco com tipo do campo *timestamp without time zone*, mas preciso saber qual é o tempo de diferença com a hora atual que no caso seria:

> ```
> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
> ```

Comment: não cara não tem muito a ver não aqui eu preciso tirar a hora do banco e pegar a hora atual tirar a diferença em minutos  e ai fazer as validações

Comment: não estou usando a classe date tenho quase certeza que é algo com a função microtime() mais não sei muito bem como manipular ela

Comment: Dá perfeitamente para criar um `date` com um `timestamp` vindo do banco de dados, o que vai tornar o problema numa diferença normal de datas em php

Comment: então cara mais mesmo assim não irei obter a diferença entre horas minutos e tals para que possa ser validado se mais de 1 hora gerar token novo, se não token ainda válido .... isso são apenas if simples e tals que ja tenho só to precisando pegar  essa diferença mesmo em horas minutos e tal ?

Comment: Oservando [Como calcular a diferença entre duas datas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/como-calcular-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-duas-datas), você quer calcular dois intervalos de datas assim não é ? `SELECT '2017-08-01 09:30:00'::TIMESTAMP - TO_CHAR(now(), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:I:S')::TIMESTAMP;`

Comment: isso ai mais ou menos isso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em PHP, o método `diff()` da classe `DateTime` é capaz de calcular a diferença entre duas datas:

```
$agora = new DateTime();
$data = new DateTime('2020-01-25 12:21:33');

var_dump( $agora->diff($data) );
```

Saída:

```
object( DateInterval )#3 (15)
{
    ["y"]=> int(2)
    ["m"]=> int(5)
    ["d"]=> int(24)
    ["h"]=> int(2)
    ["i"]=> int(45)
    ["s"]=> int(0)
    ["weekday"]=> int(0)
    ["weekday_behavior"]=> int(0)
    ["first_last_day_of"]=> int(0)
    ["invert"]=> int(0)
    ["days"]=> int(907)
    ["special_type"]=> int(0)
    ["special_amount"]=> int(0)
    ["have_weekday_relative"]=> int(0)
    ["have_special_relative"]=> int(0)
}
```

Em Postgres:

```
-- Diferenca total em Segundos
SELECT extract(epoch from ('2020-01-25 12:21:33' - now()));


-- Diferenca por partes:
SELECT
    date_part( 'year', age('2020-01-25 12:21:33',now()) ) AS qtd_anos,
    date_part( 'month', age('2020-01-25 12:21:33',now()) ) AS qtd_meses,
    date_part( 'day', age('2020-01-25 12:21:33',now()) ) AS qtd_dias,
    date_part( 'hour', age('2020-01-25 12:21:33',now()) ) AS qtd_horas,
    date_part( 'minute', age('2020-01-25 12:21:33',now()) ) AS qtd_minutos,
    date_part( 'second', age('2020-01-25 12:21:33',now()) ) AS qtd_segundos;
```