# Contar quantos dias tem de hoje para a data do banco

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso criar uma aplicação em PHP que leia a data de uma coluna dentro do banco de dados em MYSQL e compare com a data de hoje, após comparar ele deve imprimir a diferença de dias.

Exemplo:
No banco contem a seguinte data:2017-08-31, na coluna 'datas'. Como hoje é dia 2017-09-28, ele teria que me retornar *29 dias*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se quiser utilizar pelo próprio MySQL, as vezes a consulta fica mais rápida, pois não precisa de manipulação pelo PHP:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATA_TABELA) AS DIFERENCA_DIAS FROM TABELA_DATAS
```

Referência: 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_datediff.asp

Comment: Esse AS DIFERENCA_DIAS, o que seria? Não entendi.

Comment: É um ALIAS para o nome do campo que vai conter o número 29, de acordo com o teu exemplo. Ai você chama no PHP o valor do resultado como $diferenca = $S['DIFERENCA_DIAS']; https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: Fiz do seu modo e funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Uma das formas de fazer isso é usando a classe [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php), a mesma possui o método diff que retorna um objeto `DateInterval`, que representa o intervalo entre duas datas distintas:

Seguindo o exemplo de datas:

```
$data1 = new DateTime( '2013-12-11' );
$data2 = new DateTime( '1994-04-17' );

$intervalo = $data1->diff( $data2 );

echo "Intervalo é de {$intervalo->y} anos, {$intervalo->m} meses e {$intervalo->d} dias";
```

Resposta de: [Como calcular a diferença entre duas datas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/como-calcular-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-duas-datas/70)

Answer (score 1):

```
$dt_hoje   = date('Y-m-d');
$dt_banco  = '2017-08-22';
// Usa a função strtotime() e pega o timestamp das duas datas:
$dt_hoje   = strtotime($dt_hoje);
$dt_banco  = strtotime($dt_banco);
// Calcula a diferença de segundos entre as duas datas:
$diferenca = $dt_banco - $dt_hoje;
// Calcula a diferença de dias
$dias      = (int)floor( $diferenca / (60 * 60 * 24));
print_r($dias);
```