# Onde estou errando para calcular a idade?

Tags: php, datetime, data

```
function idadeAluno($dataNasci){
    $nasci = new dateTime($this->dataNasci);
    $agora = new dateTime();
    $idade = $this->nasci - $this->agora;
    echo 'idade aluno:'.$this->idade.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Duplicata de [Como calcular a diferença entre duas datas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57/5878)

Comment: Não dá para reproduzir o erro, pois tem uma série de problemas no post (por exemplo, de onde vem o $this?) Importante postar um [mcve] que apresente o problema ocorrido.

Answer (score 3):

Para calcular a diferença entre dois `DateTime`'s, basta usar o [método `diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.diff.php):

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2000-01-20");
$date2 = new DateTime("2019-04-23");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo "diferença " . $interval->y . " anos, " . $interval->m." meses, ".$interval->d." dias";
```

O resultado é um [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.dateinterval.php), que possui os valores da diferença devidamente "quebrados" em anos, meses e dias. Neste caso a saída é:

> diferença 19 anos, 3 meses, 3 dias

Se quiser somente a quantidade de anos, sem se importar com meses ou dias, basta pegar o valor de `$interval->y`.

Só lembrando que a quantidade de anos é sempre arredondada para baixo:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2018-01-20"); // 20/jan/2018
$date2 = new DateTime("2019-01-19"); // 19/jan/2019
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo "diferença " . $interval->y;
```

No exemplo acima, o valor de `$interval->y` é zero. Mesmo que falte um dia para completar um ano, e tecnicamente a idade seja 0,999... anos, o valor é arredondado para baixo e o resultado é zero. Somente em 20 de janeiro de 2019 é que completará 1 ano.

---

Há alguns *edge cases* a se considerar. Por exemplo, se alguém nasceu em 29 de fevereiro de 2000, em 28 de fevereiro de 2001 essa pessoa já terá 1 ano?

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2000-02-29");
$date2 = new DateTime("2001-02-28");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo "diferença " . $interval->y . " anos, " . $interval->m." meses, ".$interval->d." dias";
```

O PHP entende que não:

> diferença 0 anos, 11 meses, 30 dias

Na "vida real", realmente não sei qual deveria ser a regra (algumas APIs de outras linguagens consideram que no caso acima a diferença é de 1 ano, por exemplo), então cabe a você analisar estes casos especiais e decidir qual deveria ser o resultado.

Comment: Funciona perfeitamente com d minúsculo -> https://ideone.com/AV3Bin

Comment: @Bacco Dessa eu não sabia. É "by design"?

Comment: Coisas de PHP :D  - Quase tudo é insensivel a case em PHP, mas como é PHP, "depende do contexto" kkkkk - De qq forma, a pergunta tem uma série de problemas que podem ocasionar os mais diversos erros, além da falta do diff

Answer (score 1):

Aprenda sobre diff [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.diff.php). Isso é útil para representar a diferença entre as duas datas.

O seu código ficaria assim:

```
  function idadeAluno($dataNasci)
    {
    $nasci = new DateTime($dataNasci);
    $agora = new DateTime();
    $idade = $nasci->diff($agora);

    return "idade aluno: ".$idade->y. "<br/>"; 
     }

    echo idadeAluno("2007-03-24");
```

Answer (score 1):

Pegando carona na resposta do @hkotsubo, `DateTime` está grafado errado, além de uns errinhos de sintaxe, por exemplo quando usa `$this->dataNasci` para se referir ao parâmetro basta `$dataNasci` pois é um parâmetro e não uma propriedade.

Está aqui código corrigido:

```
class CalculaData{
    function idadeAluno($dataNasci)
    {
        $nasci = new DateTime($dataNasci);
        $agora = new DateTime("now");

        $idade = $nasci->diff($agora);
         echo "idade aluno: " . $idade->y . " anos, " . $idade->m." meses, ".$idade->d." dias";
    }
}

$calculaData = new CalculaData();

$calculaData->idadeAluno("1935-06-01");
```

Cujo o retorno é :

```
idade aluno: 83 anos, 10 meses, 13 dias
```

Comment: obrigada por mostrar os erros, é dica funcionou .