# Descobrir intervalo de tempo

Tags: php, data, strtotime

Estou tentando descobrir o intervalo de tempo entre duas strings com o `strtotime`.

Uma possui o templo completo e a outra varia entre minutos até horas, o problema é que quando são minutos, ao utilizar o `strtotime`, ele transforma os minutos (Ex: 3:00 min vira 3:00:00 hrs)

Como posso saber o intervalo de tempo?
Quero que fique a duração + o início subtraído pelo tempo atual da máquina para chegar no valor `00:02:04`.

```
//O xml me retornar assim
$duracao = '03:04'; //As vezes pode variar até horas!
$inicio  = '2019-06-02 13:07:03'; //Sempre virá nesse formato

//No caso real seria o date(Y-m-d H:i:s);
//Mas de exemplo use esta string:
$temp_maquina = '2019-06-02 13:08:03';

$t = (strtotime($duracao) + strtotime($inicio)) - strtotime($temp_maquina);

echo date("h:i:s", $t);
```

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo e como deverá ser a saída? não entendi muito a pergunta.

Comment: pode ser em milésimo o tempo restante, quero utilizar em um intervalo no javascript, é um sistema de web radio, para obter o json de volta a cada musica, invés de chama lo o tempo todo

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como calcular a diferença entre duas datas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/como-calcular-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-duas-datas)

Comment: Não, no meu caso o meu problema é que o  strtotime está transformando os minutos em horas aumentando os zeros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente, é importante ter em mente dois conceitos:

- uma data e um horário representam pontos específicos no tempo: uma data corresponde a um ponto específico do calendário (uma dia, mês e ano determinados) e um horário corresponde a um momento específico do dia
- uma duração corresponde a uma quantidade de tempo, sem relação com uma data e hora específicas

Para deixar mais claro a diferença, considere os 2 exemplos abaixo:

- a reunião será às 3 horas da tarde
- a reunião durou 3 horas

No primeiro exemplo, estou me referindo a um horário: a um momento específico do dia. Já no segundo exemplo, estou me referindo à duração da reunião: a quantidade de tempo que ela demorou (e nesse caso, eu não disse que horas ela começou ou terminou - eu disse apenas a quantidade de tempo, sem nenhuma referência ao horário em si).

O que pode confundir esses dois conceitos é o fato de ambos usarem as mesmas palavras (dias, horas, minutos, etc). Para piorar, existe o costume de escrevê-los da mesma maneira. Por exemplo: "10:00:00" pode ser tanto 10 horas da manhã quanto uma duração de 10 horas (como muitos cronômetros costumam mostrar). Mas apesar de muitas vezes serem escritos da mesma maneira, eles são conceitos diferentes que não devem ser confundidos.

Obviamente podemos relacioná-los (uma data somada à uma duração resulta em outra data, a diferença entre duas datas/horas é uma duração, etc), mas eles não são a mesma coisa.

---

Dito isso, a função `strtotime` trabalha com datas e horas, mas não com durações (ela pode até "funcionar" em alguns casos, mas será por coincidência). Podemos ver na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php) que, quando ela recebe uma string no formato "xx:yy", esta é interpretada como "hora:minuto" (as horas do dia, e não uma duração de x horas e y minutos). Então de qualquer forma, você não deve usar `strtotime` para durações.

Para trabalhar com durações, o PHP (em versões >= 5.3.0) possui a classe [`DateInterval`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php). Infelizmente ela não consegue converter uma string no formato "xx:yy" diretamente para uma duração, então temos que fazer isso manualmente:

```
$duracao = '03:04';
$partes = explode(':', $duracao);
$len = count($partes);
if ($len == 2) { // só tem minutos e segundos
  $horas = 0;
  $minutos = $partes[0];
  $segundos = $partes[1];
} else if ($len == 3) { // tem horas, minutos e segundos
  $horas = $partes[0];
  $minutos = $partes[1];
  $segundos = $partes[2]; 
}
// cria o DateInterval
$d = new DateInterval("PT{$horas}H{$minutos}M{$segundos}S");
```

Aqui estou considerando os casos "03:04" (3 minutos e 4 segundos), ou "01:03:04" (uma hora, 3 minutos e 4 segundos), que você disse que são os casos possíveis (caso haja mais, basta adicionar no código acima).

Em seguida eu crio o `DateInterval`, e a string passada para o [construtor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) deve estar no formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations): a letra "P" no início indica uma duração, e a letra "T" indica que os campos a seguir correspondem ao horário (horas, minutos e segundos). Em seguida eu coloco os respectivos valores, seguidos de sua unidade de tempo ("H" para horas, "M" para minutos e "S" para segundos).

Em seguida, basta somar este `DateInterval` ao `DateTime` inicial, e depois subtrair a outra data:

```
$inicio  = new DateTime('2019-06-02 13:07:03');
$temp_maquina = new DateTime('2019-06-02 13:08:03');
$result = $inicio->add($d)->diff($temp_maquina);
echo $result->format("%H:%I:%S"); // 00:02:04
```

O [construtor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) de `DateTime` recebe as strings que você indicou (mas você pode simplesmente usar `new DateTime()` para a data/hora atual). Em seguida o [método `add`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) soma a data e a duração, resultando em outro `DateTime`.

A seguir, subtraímos `$temp_maquina` (usando o [método `diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)) e o resultado é outro `DateInterval`, contendo a diferença entre as datas. Por fim, usamos o [método `format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) para formatar a duração. O resultado é:

> 00:02:04

Que corresponde a uma duração de 2 minutos e 4 segundos.

Answer (score 0):

No PHP existe uma função que faz o cálculo dessa diferença de tempo, você precisa informar a data como `DateTime` e usar a função `diff` para realizar a operação, segue a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.diff.php) completa.

> Lembrando que essa função irá funcionar apenas para a versão 5.3.0 ou superior do PHP.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); //Fuso horario de brasilia

// calcula milissegundos
$t = microtime(true);
$micro = sprintf("%06d",($t - floor($t)) * 1000000);

// Datas para determinar o intervalo
$data_1 = new DateTime(date('2019-06-02 00:00:00.000000')); //primeira data
$data_2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$micro, $t)); //segunda data
$intervalo = $data_1->diff($data_2); //função para encontrar o intervalo
// saida
echo $intervalo->format('%y/') . 
$intervalo->format('%m/') . 
$intervalo->format('%d ') . 
$intervalo->format('%h:') . 
$intervalo->format('%i:') . 
$intervalo->format('%s.') . 
$intervalo->format('%F');
```

Exemplo de saída:

> 0/0/0 15:6:17.441868