# PHP - Somatória de horas para sistema de ponto

Tags: php

Estou tendo um problema com o cálculo do saldo de horas do meu sistema de ponto. Basicamente, preciso saber o quanto de horas um funcionário tem, comparando o Tempo que ele trabalhou no mês com o Tempo que era previsto ele trabalhar durante esse período.

No meu código eu consigo calcular tranquilamente, inclusive se o saldo for negativo, porém em algum momento ele se perde e eu não consegui entender ainda, poderiam me ajudar?

```
//Teste funcionando
//$horasTrabalhadas = '140:30:00';
//$horasPrevistas = '141:30:00';
//Saldo de horas: -01:00:00

//Teste com erro
$horasTrabalhadas = '141:50:00';
$horasPrevistas = '144:00:00';
// Resultado esperado: 02:10 // Resultado que está aparecendo: 03:50

echo "Saldo de horas: " . calculaTempo($horasPrevistas, $horasTrabalhadas);

function calculaTempo($hora_inicial, $hora_final) {
    $i = 1;
    $tempo_total='';

    $tempos = array($hora_final, $hora_inicial);

    foreach($tempos as $tempo) {
        $segundos = 0;

        list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', $tempo);

        $segundos += $h * 3600;
        $segundos += $m * 60;
        $segundos += $s;

        $tempo_total[$i] = $segundos;

        $i++;
    }

    $segundos = $tempo_total[1] - $tempo_total[2];

    $horas = floor($segundos / 3600);
    $segundos -= $horas * 3600;
    $minutos = str_pad((floor($segundos / 60)), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $segundos -= $minutos * 60;
    $segundos = str_pad($segundos, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    return "$horas:$minutos:$segundos";
}
```

Desde já agradeço a todos. :)

Comment: Veja se ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/388495/112052

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Assumi que você está apenas utilizado isso para fins de estudo então não irei colocar em debate que essa não é a melhor forma de armazenar tempo para realizar cálculos com horas, dias etc para evitar [POGs](https://www.google.com/search?q=pog%20na%20programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o) como essa. Feito isso vamos lá.
Tomei a liberdade de trazer o saldo de horas negativo ou positivo;

```
<?php

function calculaTempo($horasPrevistas, $horasTrabalhadas) {

    $horasPrevistas  = asSeconds($horasPrevistas);
    $horasTrabalhadas    = asSeconds($horasTrabalhadas);
    $segundos   = $horasPrevistas - $horasTrabalhadas;
    $deveHoras  = $horasPrevistas > $horasTrabalhadas;
    $segundos   = getFullHour($segundos);
    var_dump($segundos);
    if ($deveHoras) {
        $data = ['saldo_negativo' => $segundos];
        return $data;
    }

    $data = ['saldo_positivo' => $segundos];
    return $data;
 }


function getFullHour($seconds) {
    $seconds = intval($seconds); //Converte para inteiro

    $negativo = $seconds < 0; //Verifica se é um valor negativo

    if ($negativo) {
        $seconds = -$seconds; //Converte o negativo para positivo para poder fazer os calculos
    }

    $horas = floor($seconds / 3600);
    $min = floor(($seconds - ($horas * 3600)) / 60);
    $sec = floor($seconds % 60);

    $sign = $negativo ? '-' : ''; //Adiciona o sinal de negativo se necessário

    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $horas, $min, $sec);
}

function asSeconds($totalTime)
{
    $segundos = 0;
    list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', $totalTime);
    $segundos += $h * 3600;
    $segundos += $m * 60;
    $segundos += $s;
    return $segundos;
}



$trabalhadas = '144:50:00';
$previstas = '144:00:00';

$calculo = calculaTempo($previstas, $trabalhadas);

if (!empty($calculo['saldo_negativo'])) {
    echo "Saldo de horas negativo é : " . $calculo['saldo_negativo'] . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo "Saldo de horas positivo é : " . $calculo['saldo_positivo'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Parte dessa resposta está nesse post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/290020/4800
Considere dar +1 se achar útil :)

Comment: agradeço imensamente Marcos, era isso mesmo. Um abraço.

Comment: Sinceramente eu penso que o SO deveria perguntar ao "down voter" o motivo e mostrar ao autor do post/resposta os motivos . Alguns códigos são para fins de estudo e aprendizado da linguagem e esse exemplo que fiz foi pensando nisso. Coisas desse tipo só desanima ajudar o fórum crescer, já que usamos algum tempo para responder

Comment: verdade cara, eu sinceramente não entendi essa quantidade de down voter, quem votou deveria no mínimo justificar.